# Returned type of RTK mutation

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I want to use mutation result as props like following code:

```
function Foo() {
  const [updateEmail, result] = useUpdateEmailMutation()
  return (
    <>
      <Bar result={result} />
      <Baz result={result} />
    </>
```

I wonder I can give some specific types to result props of Bar other than any type.

```
interface IProps {
 result: any <- here
}

const Foo: React.FC<IProps> = ({result}) => {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would [type the according endpoint definition](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript#typing-query-and-mutation-endpoints)

```
const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    updateEmail: build.mutation<ResultType, QueryArg>({
      query: (arg) => { /*...*/ },
    }),
  }),
})
```

Comment: Are you saying I can use `ResultType`? I think type of `result` returned from `useUpdateEmailMutation` is different from `ResultType`. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: The type you pass into that `TypeResult` there will be the type of `data` returned from the `useUpdateEmailMutation` call.

Comment: Do you mean I can use `ResultType` if I deconstruct `result` in `Foo` function?

Comment: `result.data` will be of the type `ResultType`. I don't know what exactly you mean be "use ResultType` - it will already be of that type.